# update single item within array where multiple conditions apply to any array item

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a basic mongoose model with an attribute `instruments` which represents an array. Therefore it consists multiple items, which each have the following attributes: `name`, `counter`. The document itself has an autogenerated `_id` of type `ObjectID`.

**Model**

```
var ParticipationSchema = new Schema({
    instruments: [{
      name: String,
      counter: Number
    }],
// etc.
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
```

I'd like now to change exactly 1 item within the `instruments` array, only if it matches the following requirements:

1. The document id has to equal `58f3c77d789330486ccadf40`
2. The `instruments`-item's `name` which should be changed has to equal `'instrument-1'`
3. The `instrument`-item's `counter` has to be lower than `3`

**Query**

```
let someId = '58f3c77d789330486ccadf40';
let instrumentName = 'instrument-1'
let counter = 3;

Participation.update(
{
    $and: [          
      { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(someId) },
      { 'instruments.name': instrumentName },
      { 'instruments.counter': { $lt: counter } }
    ]},
    {
      $set: {
        'instruments.$.currentcounter' : counter
      }
    },
    (err, raw) => {
      // ERROR HANDLING
    }
});
```

Let's assume I have 3 entries within the `instruments`-attribute:

```
"instruments": [
  {
    "name": "instrument-1",
    "counter": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "instrument-1",
    "counter": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "instrument-1",
    "counter": 2
  }
]
```

**Desired behaviour:** change the first element's `counter` attribute to `3`, no matter, when running the update code 1 time, do no action when running it more times.

**Actual behaviour:**

- it changes the 1st element's `counter` attribute to `3` when running it the 1st time
- it changes the 2nds element's `counter` attribute to `3` when running it the 2nd time
- it changes the 3rds element's `counter` attribute to `3` when running it the 3rd time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the queries are `and`ed, they don't seem to run element-wise. To resolve the issue, `$elemMatch` can be used:

```
Participation.update({
         _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(someId),
         'instruments': {
            $elemMatch: {
              'name': instrumentName,
              'counter': { $lt: counter } }}
      },
      // etc.
```

**more info:**

- API reference on [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)
- Thanks to @VEERAM's for pointing out that this kind of behaviour is also documented the [mongodb homepage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents).

Comment: Just for information. Those queries are implicitly anded. So you don't need `$and` operator. The behaviour you are seeing is documented here.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents